# Tikz : pgfmathresult after a pgfmathparse returns 0

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a generic code to draw a cycle graph. I used a code found in the net to create the nodes... But when it comes to re-use `pgfmathparse` and `pgfmathresult`, I only get as value for the second `\pgfmathresult` ... 0. Even in this example, I've put `\pgfmathparse{int(2)}`, and in the second line, he draws me a vertex with the label "0" ... Which should be "2"... Right ? I don't understand what I'm missing.

```
    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!0, draw, minimum size=10pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, auto,swap]
      \foreach \i in {1,...,4}{%
        \pgfmathparse{(\i-1)*90+floor(\i/5)*22.5}
        \node[vertex] (N-\i) at (\pgfmathresult:2) [thick] {}; % Put some nodes N-1 to N-4
        \pgfmathparse{int(2)}
        \node (muck) at (0,0) {\pgfmathresult}; % DISPLAY 0 AS RESULT
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You need to do         `\node (muck) at (0,0) {\pgfmathparse{int(2)}\pgfmathresult};`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @cfr percusse has now addressed the reason in his answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, thank you. (Or thanks to percusse!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TikZ uses `\pgfmathparse{...}\pgfmathresult` mechanism for its own computations for node size, background path etc. just as you would access it for your own computations. Hence it gets overwritten a lot.

Here, you make a computation but call the value too late. So `\node` also called it and it might even also give other values not equal to zero depending on what has happened before the node is placed. In this case the `y` coordinate of the node, for example, this gives `1`

```
    \node (muck) at (0,1) {\pgfmathresult}; % DISPLAY 1 AS RESULT
```

That's why you have to be "quick" as Gonzalo Medina commented that you call it immediately after you do a computation.

In the first instance of `\pgfmathparse` you use the same thing but that one seemingly works. Why? It works because the value is called before node computations took place, since it only parses the input but doesn't actually start doing the node creation. So we are lucky. For example,

```
\node[vertex,line width=1pt] (N-\i) at (\pgfmathresult:2) [thick] {};
```

will not work since we did an internal computation line width.

Comment: In such situations I usually use `\edef\myvalue{\pgfmathresult}` so it's not later lost.  Or `\xdef` if I need it in  a later iteration.

Comment: @A.Ellett If it's just specific for the current spin of the loop, then you can use the `evaluate` key for that. For use of outside use indeed `\xdef` is the way to go.

Comment: @cfr Pfff, now I get it. I need more coffee. Will fix now.

Comment: @percusse (+1) Now *I* get it, too ;).

Answer (score 12):

Precusse's answer explains what is going on. This is one of the reasons that I just always use `\pgfmathsetmacro{}{...}` instead of `\pgfmathparse{...}`, `\pgfmathresult` combination:

[image]

### Notes:

- There is also a `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` when integer results are desired.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyPgfMathResult}{}% Ensure that we are not already using this somewhere

\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!0, draw, minimum size=10pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, auto,swap]
      \foreach \i in {1,...,4}{%
        %\pgfmathparse{(\i-1)*90+floor(\i/5)*22.5}% replaced with \pgfmathsetmacro
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyPgfMathResult}{{(\i-1)*90+floor(\i/5)*22.5}}%
        \node[vertex] (N-\i) at (\MyPgfMathResult:2) [thick] {}; % Put some nodes N-1 to N-4
        %\pgfmathparse{int(2)} replaced with \pgfmathsetmacro
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyPgfMathResult}{int(2)}%
        \node (muck) at (0,0) {\MyPgfMathResult}; % 
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```