# Relative node positioning with calc library

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, calculations

Hi I'm trying to place same nodes relative to each other. I'm trying to place a node in the middle between two other nodes, but also half a cm to the right.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (p4) {$\hat{4}$} ;
\node[below=1cm of p4] (p3) {$3$} ;
\node[right=3cm of p4] (p1) {$\hat{1}$} ;
\node[below=1cm of p1] (p2) {$2$} ;
\node[below right={1/sqrt(2)}cm of p4] (v1) {$v_1$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I don't get why this isn't working... I get the following error

> Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `c' or`cm' (in
>   '{1/sqrt(2)}cm ').

Comment: Try `below right=1cm/sqrt(2) of p4` (or `below right=1/sqrt(2)*1cm of p4`)... and use the `positioning` TikZ library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must:

- Add the `positioning` library.
- Use `\pgfmathparse` to *calculate* the `1/sqrt(2)` expresion.
- Use `\pgfmathresult` where is the result of calculation.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (p4) {$\hat{4}$} ;
  \node[below=1cm of p4] (p3) {$3$} ;
  \node[right=3cm of p4] (p1) {$\hat{1}$} ;
  \node[below=1cm of p1] (p2) {$2$} ;
  \pgfmathparse{1/sqrt(2)}
  \node[below right=\pgfmathresult cm of p4] (v1) {$v_1$} ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

Or if you don't use some *unit* like `cm`, you don't need `\pgfmathparse`.

### Edit

To avoid problems with `\pgfmathparse{}` and `\pgfmathresult` you can use your *own* macro with `\pgfmathsetmacro{...}`. This change avoids the problem showed by @percusse.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (p4) {$\hat{4}$} ;
\node[below=1cm of p4] (p3) {$3$} ;
\node[right=3cm of p4] (p1) {$\hat{1}$} ;
\node[below=1cm of p1] (p2) {$2$} ;
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myroot}{1/sqrt(2)} % <- 
\node[line width=3mm,below right=\myroot cm of p4] (v1) {$v_1$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Although this is not relevant to this specific problem, it may be useful for other cases.

Comment: Use `[line width=3mm,below right=\pgfmathresult cm of p4]` as the option and you'll see a nice problem with this. Use pgfmathresult as soon as possible before any other math computation intervenes.

Comment: @percusse Ah, i see, do you have an explanation for this? it seems better don't put *units* and to avoid using of `\pgfmathresult`.

Comment: I tried to explain here a bit http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191252/3235 TikZ can understand the math as in the other answer but you need to multiply it by 1cm or 1mm or 1pt at the end. So you don't need `\pgfmathparse` at all.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `positioning`-library of *tikz* to position nodes relative to each other.

Try the follwing:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (p4) {$\hat{4}$};
  \node[below=1cm of p4] (p3) {$3$};
  \node[right=3cm of p4] (p1) {$\hat{1}$};
  \node[below=1cm of p1] (p2) {$2$};
  \node[below right={1/sqrt(2)} of p4] (v1) {$v_1$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered Image]

> Update: If you want to use another unit than *cm* (*in*, *pt*, ...)

The above code uses *tikz*'s default of *1cm* as base unit. If you want to use another base unit for your picture you can set this in the *tikzpicture*'s options. This way you don't need to set the unit after the calculation of sqrt() and inhibit the error.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in, y=1in]
 \node[below=1cm] ... % use of cm
 \node[below=1]   ... % use of global unit (e.g. in)
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do analytic geometry in tikz. 
That is, add a polar/rectangular displacement and add two coordinates/vectors.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newdimen\x
\newdimen\y
\newcommand*{\GetXY}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y};}%


\begin{document}

% ======================================= V
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % absolute
    \node at ($(1, -2) + (0.5, 1)$) (pX) {X};
    \node at ($(2, 1) - (1.5, 1)$) (pY) {Y};

    % polar coordinates wrt pA
    \node at (4, 1) (pA) {A};
    \node at ($(pA) + (30:1)$) (pAa) {Aa};
    \node at ($(pA) + (-30:1)$) (pAb) {Ab};

    % rectangular coordinates
    \node at (1, 3) (pB) {B};
    \node at ($(pB) + (-1,2)$) (pBa) {Ba};
    \node at ($(pB) - (-1,2)$) (pBb) {Bb};

    % relative
    \node at ($(pA) + (pB)$) (pABp) {ABp};
    \node at ($(pA) - (pB)$) (pABm) {ABm};

    % with x and y
            \node at (-1, -1) (pC) {C};
    \GetXY{$(pC)$};
    \node at ($(\x, -\y)$) (pCa) {Ca};

    % helpers below (feel free to commend out)
    % axis
    \node at (0, 0) (pO) {O};
    \draw[->] (pO) -- (1, 0);
    \draw[->] (pO) -- (0, 1);
    %
    \draw[dashed] (pA) -- (pAa);
    \draw[dashed] (pA) -- (pAb);
    \draw[dashed] (pB) -- (pBa);
    \draw[dashed] (pB) -- (pBb);
    \draw[dashed] (pA) -- (pABp);
    \draw[dashed] (pA) -- (pABm);
    \draw[dashed] (pC) -- (pCa);
\end{tikzpicture}
% ======================================= A

\end{document}
```