# Using every edge style to thick causes problems with pgfmathparse Mod

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

When using `every edge/.append style = {thick}`, `Mod` doesn't work as intended. Not sure, if the problem is what I am infering or is something else.

For example, consider

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\tikzset{
  every edge/.append style = {thick}% commenting this solves the problem
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (table) {};
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
  \pgfmathparse{mod(\i*72+18,360)}
  \node[] at (\pgfmathresult:3cm) (table) (p\i) {$F_\i$};
  \pgfmathparse{mod(\i*72+54,360)}
  \node[] at (\pgfmathresult:2cm) (table) (c\i) {$C_\i$};
}

\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
  \pgfmathparse{Mod(\i-2,5)+1}
  \draw[->, red] (p\i) edge (c\pgfmathresult);
  \node[right=.5cm of p\i] {\pgfmathresult};% see the result of the operation, they are random numbers
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This code causes problems with the `Mod` as it throws random numbers (at least they seem to be)

[image]

I added the `\node[right=.5cm of p\i] {\pgfmathresult};` to see the result on the operation. Interestingly if one removes the `every edge/.append style = {thick}` the operation works as intended.

What am I missing? Is there a way to set the edges to be thick and to have the `Mod` working?

Comment: I remove everything from my original file, but in there I have some styles for edges, and wanted to add it globaly. On the way, I found that the modulo gave me error, and bring it down to what you see in the MWE.

Comment: You should save the results in a macro as soon as possible.  Between using `\pgfmathparse` and calling `\pgfmathresult` you cannot be certain that TikZ hasn't itself redefined `\pgfmathresult`.  So try `\pgfmathsetmacro{...}` or after calling `\pfmathparse` call `\edef\myresult{\pgfmathresult}` before performing any thing else with either `pgf` or `TikZ`.

Comment: That random number is .5cm in pt units. Because your `\pgfmathresult` is overwritten during line thickness setting. And `thick` setting internally does computations about line width hence also overwrites `\pgfmathresult`. This is a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Maybe this ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191248/tikz-pgfmathresult-after-a-pgfmathparse-returns-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How's this

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\tikzset{
  every edge/.append style = {thick}% commenting this solves the problem
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (table) {};

\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{int(mod(\i*72+18,360))}
  \node[] at ($(\myresult:3cm)+(table)$) (p\i) {$F_\i$};
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{int(mod(\i*72+54,360))}
  \node[] at ($(\myresult:2cm)+(table)$) (c\i) {$C_\i$};
}

\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
  \pgfmathparse{int(Mod(\i-2,5)+1)}
  \edef\myresult{\pgfmathresult}%%
  \draw[->, red,every edge/.append style={thick}] (p\i) edge (c\myresult);
  \node[right=.5cm of p\i] {\myresult};% see the result of the operation, they are random numbers
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Resulting image (not quite sure how you wanted this to look)

[image]

Your syntax for the nodes is a bit confusing.  I'm not sure what you intended by

```
\node at (<location>) (<node name>) (<node name>) {<content>};
```

So I modified your syntax a bit.

Also, `mod` will return a decimal value.  You need integer values.  So, I've modified that part of your `\pgfmathparse` computations.

Also I illustrate to *safer* ways to retrieve and use the values of `\pgfmathparse`.  Do one of the following two

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{<computation>}
```

or

```
\pgfmathparse{<computation>}
\edef\myresult{\pgfmathresult}
```

The problem is that `TikZ` and `pgf` both actively use `\pgfmathresult`.  So you want to save the value first before you do anything where you might need it.

Comment: `\foreach \i[evaluate={\myresult=int(Mod(\i-2,5)+1);}] in {1,...,5}{` does the same thing but easier to read probably.